# What is the syntax to comment a line in a tibco ems script

Tags: tibco-ems

In a script which looks like below

`create queue one

create queue two

create topic three`



How can I comment a line?

Answer (score 2):

I could find noting in either the tool itself or documentation.

The closest thing to comments you could do is:

```
echo off some comments here
```

tibemsadmin does not fail, and don't react to extra parameters. The "echo" command is harmless... so it is a great candidate.

Of course, you might prefer "echo on".

Not a great solution, but the only one I find.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the script that will be executed by tibemsadmin binary? You can try to prepend "#" in the front of the line which you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run a command against the EMS server that is a comment.  The easiest is to let it crash.

I've use 
     // Comment line "Creating queue for XYZ process"

However it still generates an error which wasn't a problem until we have just implemented continuous deployments for EMS and Tibco BW Ears, and it stopped when there was an error coming back from the command.

You could write a quick pre-processor that reads each line of the EMS script file and spits out a separate file that you can just run without errors.  I'd  do something like

(Your language of choice) 
for each line in the file
   if line starts with // then 
       do nothing
   else
       write it to the other file
end loop